# Using date range filter for primeng table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng, date-range

I have the following code for implementing a date range filter in the PrimeNG table.

```
                    <th class="filter_header">
                      <p-calendar
                       
                        (onSelect)="historyTable.filter($event,'release_datetime', 'dateRangeFilter')"
                        placeholder="Search by release date"
                        [appendTo]="historyTable"
                        [(ngModel)]="rangeDates"
                      </p-calendar>
                    </th>
```

and in the component, I have `FilterUtils` defined as follows:

```
FilterUtils['dateRangeFilter'] = (value, filter): boolean => {
  if (filter === undefined || filter === null) {
    return true;
  }

  if (value === undefined || value === null) {
    return false;
  }
  console.log(value);
  if (this.rangeDates[0] <= value && this.rangeDates[1] >= value) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

But this is not working. If anyone can guide me right direction, that would be helpful.

I am getting the `value` as undefined. I have tried with `$event.target.value`, but it is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your calendar like below. Instead of using `$event`, you need `rangeDates` as filter.

```typescript
    <p-calendar
      [(ngModel)]="rangeDates"
      (onSelect)="historyTable.filter(rangeDates,'release_datetime', 'dateRangeFilter')"
      placeholder="Search by release date"
      [appendTo]="historyTable">
    </p-calendar>
```